# Wrong syntax coloring for multiline comment in Haskell file

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntax

As shown in the following screencast, when I open this Haskell file (extension `hs`), a long multi-line comment is not recognized appropriately.

Based [a previous question of mine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27450/syntax-coloring-is-inaccurate-for-html-files-with-css-code-in-it) I've verified that `:syntax sync fromstart` correctly recolors the syntax. However, putting it into `~/.vim/after/syntax/hs.html` doesn't see to have effect.

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `haskell`, not `hs`, so you need to put your code in `~/.vim/after/syntax/haskell.vim` (see `:help syn-files`).

You can see the name of the syntax with

```
:setlocal syntax?
```

(add `:verbose` to see where it came from).

In general, the value of the `syntax` option is the same as the value of the `filetype` option, so it is usually enough to check

```
:setlocal filetype?
```

Note however that for `ftplugins` using the filetype mechanism, you have some more freedom on names (`:help ftplugin-name`).